# Weird difference between "for(std::vector<int>::iterator it = my_vec.begin(); it != my_vec.end(); ++it)" and "for(int i:my_vec)"

Tags: c++

I've seen many forums say that `for(std::vector<int>::iterator it = my_vec.begin(); it != my_vec.end(); ++it)` and `for(int i:my_vec)` are the same. But when I ran the following codes (PART A and PART B):

```cpp
class my_class
{
public:
  void increase_age(){age_++;}

private:
  int age_;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<my_class> my_vec={smth,smth,smth,...};

  // PART A
  for (std::vector<my_class>::iterator it = my_vec.begin(); it != my_vec.end(); it++)
  { 
    // age is successfully increased!
    it->increase_age();
  }

  // PART B
  for (my_class c:my_vec)
  {
    // age does not increase at all when I checked outside this loop
    c.increase_age();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I realised that PART B does not increase the `age` at all. Does this mean that when I do `my_class c:my_vec`, `c` is actually only a copy of an element in `my_vec`? Or do I have other misconceptions about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `(my_class c : my_vec)`, the `c` is a copy a corresponding  element. Whereas in `it->increase_age()` you dereference the iterator, which has access to the actual element of the container.

In the case of `my_class c`, the `increase_age()` invoked on a local (to the body of the loop) copy. So, no mutation of the elements in the `my_vec`.

You can have the same effect, if declare the `c` as a reference to `my_class`:

```
for (my_class &c : my_vec)
    c.increase_age();
```